# Multiplicativity of Euler–Poincaré characteristics of cohomology of pro-$p$ groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, profinite-groups

While reading a paper, I found a mentioning that for an extension $1 \rightarrow H \rightarrow G \rightarrow N \rightarrow 1$ of pro-$p$ groups, the Euler–Poincaré characteristics $\chi(H)$, $\chi(G)$, and $\chi(N)$, if defined (for $H^{i}(H,\mathbb{F}_{p}), H^{i}(G, \mathbb{F}_{p}), H^{i}(N, \mathbb{F}_{p})$), satisfy the relation $\chi(G) = \chi(H) \cdot \chi(N)$. The paper referred to the book Galois cohomology of Serre, and I found it in an exercise (exercise (c) in page 29 I.§ 4.1).

I find this statement surprising and have not found a reference yet.
Is there some simple explanation for this fact?

If there is some reference for the proof of this fact (in group cohomology) or a more general cohomology theory, it will help me a lot.

Comment: For general $G$ virtually torsion-free this is Brown, Chapter IX, Proposition 7.3(d) (page 250).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Thank you very much for your helpful answer. I will study that part!